# How do I use https with PutMarkLogic?

Tags: apache-nifi, marklogic

I'm using `DefaultMarkLogicDatabaseClientService` 1.9.1.3-incubator in NiFi 1.11.4. MarkLogic 10.0-4 is running AWS and has an app server where SSL is configured at the AWS level.

How do I configure the `DefaultMarkLogicDatabaseClientService` to use HTTPS without needing an SSL Context Service?

Details:

Before SSL was set up, the `DefaultMarkLogicDatabaseClientService` was able to connect. Once SSL was set up, I'd get this error:

> PutMarkLogic[id=bbb8f3c3-7d83-3fb7-454f-9da7d64fa3f6] Failed to properly initialize Processor. If still scheduled to run, NiFi will attempt to initialize and run the Processor again after the 'Administrative Yield Duration' has elapsed. Failure is due to com.marklogic.client.MarkLogicIOException: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{my-host:8010, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=my-host/my-IP:8010 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}: com.marklogic.client.MarkLogicIOException: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{my-host:8010, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=my-ost/my-IP:8010 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}

Okay, seems like it's not successful using protocol HTTP for a server that needs HTTPS. I see that the service can be configured to use an SSL Context Service, but I'm not looking to do client authentication. (Setting this up requires a truststore or keystore.)

If I replace the `PutMarkLogic` processor that uses the `DefaultMarkLogicDatabaseClientService` with an `InvokeHTTP` processor, I can specify the full URL, including "https://", without needing an SSL Context Services (but then I don't get the batching that I get with `PutMarkLogic`). I'd like to simply tell the MarkLogic service to use HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an `SSLContextService` with a truststore (that contains the public certificate of the MarkLogic server) populated and *no* keystore populated should work in this situation.